# Проблема с вычислениями

Tags: java, математика

Проблема вот в чем. Мне нужно вычислять косинус угла. НО происходила ошибка и я решил проверить его вычисление.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a = Math.cos(89);
        System.out.println(a);

    }

}
```

К моему удивлению компилятор выдал 0.5101770449416689, хотя посчитав на калькуляторе я получил 0,01745240643.В чем проблема?

Comment: Видимо в понимании чем градус от радиана отличается?

Answer (score 4):

Вот как верно считать косинус:

```
double degrees = 89.0;
double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);

System.out.format("The value of pi is %.4f%n", Math.PI);
System.out.format("The cosine of %.1f degrees is %.4f%n", degrees, Math.cos(radians));
```

Вывод:

```
The value of pi is 3.1416
The cosine of 89.0 degrees is 0.0175
```

Comment: а если надо просто присвоить значение косинуса переменной а не выводить его?

Comment: Присвойте переменной: `Math.cos(radians)`